# "package javax.persistence does not exist" using spring-data-jpa and IntelliJ

Tags: maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm starting a project using spring-data-jpa in IntelliJ but I am failing to load javax.persistence ("package javax.persistence does not exist").

I have been at it for four hours with what seems be be a very simple problem.  I used the standard IntelliJ UI to create the project and selected the spring framework and spring-data-jpa options.

My only code is:

```
import javax.persistence.entity;

@entity
public class customer {

}
```

The project fails to build and the tool tips in the IDE say "Can not resolve symbol persistence"  What am I missing?

My directory structure can be found below:
[image]

Comment: What is your build tool? Please post your gradle/maven/etc file if you are using those. Also, post a picture of your directory structure

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii ahh I am new to Java EE and I am not using any build tool outside of what is built in or default to IntelliJ.  Ill add the dir structure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All I needed to do was add the hibernate libs from maven through the project structure dialog (hibernate-entitymanager)

Comment: Add hibernate-entitymanager to pom.xml.

Answer (score 10):

In java 11 (released 2018), the java EE libraries were moved from the built-in core to optional dependencies (See http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320). So you may need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

(hibernate-entitymanager has this as a dependency so that's probably why adding it fixed the problem - see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.6.15.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.6.15.Final.pom)

Also related: In 2017, Java EE was transferred to Eclipse and renamed to Jakarta EE (Oracle owned the name "Java").

The latest imports are now under "jakarta": eg `import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;`.

Hibernate 5 still uses JPA 2.2 (javax) rather but Hibernate 6 uses JPA 3.0 (jakarta). Ensure you do not have both hibernate 5 and 6 in your `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 5):

Three things:

Firstly you type "Entity" wrong. Java classes are case sensitive so it should be @Entity.

Secondly, javax.persistence is not always packaged with the core JDK so you need to download it. You can get it here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2

Finally, your directory structure can result in some issues. I recommend changing it to

src (directory)

-> main (directory)

-> -> java (directory)

-> -> -> Driver (file)

-> -> -> Data.xml (file)

-> -> -> customer (file)

Comment: Sorry, in this model is main a sub directory of src then Java a subdir of main? Or is main a main class

Comment: main and java are directories. Customer is a file. Also you need to put Driver and data in java directory as well

Comment: @Chi-YougJefferyLii  no luck, still the same erros

Comment: Can you do 2 things: open up external libraries post screenshot of that, then type java -version in a console and tell results?

Comment: I am using java 12.0.1 and the only thing in the external lib folder is jdk 12.0.1

Comment: Did you type java -version in the console? What was the exact response? The terminal in intellij will work too.

Comment: Well Java isn't on the path for some reason so I had to navigate to the Java home DIR to get it to print out  Java version 12.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193572/discussion-between-chi-young-jeffrey-lii-and-pmaurais).

Answer (score 0):

You might have added hibernates in library, instead of modules in project structure.